# d3 selection.attributes.key.nodevalue doesn't return the current DOM values

Tags: javascript, html, dom, d3.js, svg

Whenever I log the `selection.attributes` , it logs the values that are exactly required, for example if there's an attribute called `y` it would log the same value that the `rect` has in the DOM at the runtime, but whenever I try to access that value using `selection.attributes.y.nodeValue` it instead returns the original value of the `rect` that it was rendered with.

My question is that if the actual attributes object has the current values then why does it return t he different value when I try to access the key (in this case `y.nodeValue`) in that object?

For further explanation:

Here's my code for logging object and code for logging the retrieval of  the value:

```
var notLiveYAttributes = chart.select("#not-live" + i + " rect.not-live")[0][0].attributes;
              console.log(notLiveYAttributes);
              console.log(notLiveYAttributes.y.value);
```

**Output:**

[image]

What am I missing here and how can I retrieve the current values of the attributes (y and height) instead of when it was originally rendered/populated?

Comment: Did you try differents browsers?

Comment: It wasn't a browser problem, I've explained the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951771/d3-selection-attributes-key-nodevalue-doesnt-return-the-current-dom-values#comment63386583_37968197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'd say that the problem here is that your `var notLiveYAttributes` is being declared **and** initialized before any modification that you apply to the element. So, given the nature of javascript and the way javascript code is parsed, the browser logs `notLiveYAttributes` immediately, and its value may not match the current DOM value.

I made this simple fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/55ezeLef/1/

I created some `rects` with y = 10. Then, I made a transition, changing y to 50.

Even if the code to console.log the y value comes after the transition, like this:

```
rects.transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("y", 50);

var notLiveYAttributes = svg.select(".rect2")[0][0].attributes.y.value;
    console.log("the immediate value is " + notLiveYAttributes);
```

It will log `the immediate value is 10`.

But if I wait a little bit:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var notLiveYAttributes = svg.select(".rect2")[0][0].attributes.y.value;
        console.log("after waiting, the value is " + notLiveYAttributes);
}, 1500);
```

It will log `after waiting, the value is 50`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was doing, actually I was accessing the values before the transition has been applied, so the `notLiveYAttribiutes` logged the final attributes which would be applied after the transition, where as while accessing an individual value it just logged the value at the current moment. Thanks a lot, really appreciate your input.